# Light/Dark mode toggle changes background but not my function to change fill of SVG (using css variables/ GSAP/and JS)

Tags: javascript, svg, toggle, gsap, darkmode

I am trying to have a Light/Dark mode toggle in my website where it not only changes the background color, but it changes the fill color of the SVG waves I have. I have the background colors working and I created a function// timeline for the waves using GSAP but for some reason, it won't play. I have created a CodePen since I didn't know how to add GSAP into Stack. Any and all help is appreciated!  https://codepen.io/maddylobb/pen/gOXNEeQ

```js
import * as gsap from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gsap@3.9.1";

const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e){

    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        console.log("wave play");
        waveColorTL.play();
    }

    else{
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme','light'); 
        console.log("wave reverse");
        waveColorTL.reverse();
    }
    
    console.log(toggleSwitch.checked +'this is the value for the checkbox');


}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);


//GSAP function to change the fill of svg//
const waveColorTL = new gsap.timeline({paused:true});
tanWaveTL.to("#tanWave2",{duration:0.05, fill:"000"});
waveColorTL.add(tanWaveTL, "wave")
```

```css
:root {
  --lightpink: #FFC3A4;
  --white: #fff;
  --darkpurple: #2E1845;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --lightpink: #DC9C7C;
  --white: #fff;
  --darkpurple: #22152F;
}

#hero-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--lightpink);
  #tanWave {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    @include md {
      margin-top: -40px;
    }
    @include lg {
      margin-top: -60px;
    }
    @include lg {
      margin-top: -85px;
    }
  }
  .theme-switch-wrapper {
    grid-area: search;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: column;
    width: 100%;
    #light-dark-text {
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
  .theme-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
  }
  .theme-switch input {
    display: none;
  }
  .slider {
    background-color: var(--darkpurple);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  .slider:before {
    background-color: var(--white);
    bottom: 4px;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 26px;
  }
  input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: var(--white);
  }
  input:checked+.slider:before {
    transform: translateX(26px);
    background-color: var(--darkpurple);
  }
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero-2">
  <section class="theme-switch-wrapper">
    <label id="light-dark-label" class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                      <div class="slider round"></div>
                    </label>
    <p id="light-dark-text">Enable Dark Mode!</p>
  </section>
  <div id="tanWave" class="wave">
    <svg fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 28">
            <g id="tanWave2" fill="#F9D5AE">
              <path d="M94.304 14.776v12.33h15.482H0V14.764c2.453.475 8.95-.522 15.31-8.308 6.362-7.786 12.067-6.41 14.124-4.748.792.475 2.754 2.28 4.273 5.697-1.226-.83-4.059-1.899-5.578.475-1.52 2.374-.633 5.183 0 6.29 1.029 1.464 4.107 4.012 8.19 2.493 4.082-1.52 6.369-4.51 7.002-5.816 1.464-2.334 4.866-7.358 6.765-8.782 1.9-1.425 4.51-1.939 5.578-2.018 2.651-.277 8.166.57 9.02 6.172-1.582-1.148-5.103-2.635-6.527.593-1.424 3.228.91 6.25 1.899 7.359 1.82 1.384 5.863 3.062 10.326-1.306 1.7-1.424 5.84-5.198 8.783-8.901C82.108.26 87.433.046 89.728.402c2.334.119 6.955 1.567 6.765 6.41-1.701-.713-5.175-1.07-5.46 3.204-.176 2.649 1.463 4.066 3.271 4.76ZM281.859 14.776c-1.809-.694-3.448-2.111-3.271-4.76.285-4.273 3.758-3.917 5.459-3.205.19-4.842-4.431-6.29-6.765-6.41-2.294-.355-7.619-.141-10.563 3.562-2.943 3.703-7.082 7.477-8.783 8.901-4.462 4.368-8.506 2.69-10.326 1.306-.989-1.108-3.323-4.13-1.899-7.359 1.425-3.228 4.946-1.74 6.528-.593-.854-5.602-6.369-6.45-9.02-6.172-1.068.079-3.679.593-5.578 2.018-1.899 1.424-5.302 6.448-6.766 8.782-.633 1.306-2.919 4.297-7.002 5.816-4.083 1.52-7.161-1.028-8.19-2.492-.633-1.108-1.519-3.917 0-6.29 1.52-2.375 4.352-1.306 5.579-.476-1.519-3.418-3.482-5.222-4.273-5.696-2.057-1.662-7.762-3.039-14.124 4.747-6.362 7.786-12.858 8.783-15.311 8.308v12.344h94.305v-12.33Z"/>
              <path d="M188.462 14.776c-1.809-.694-3.448-2.111-3.271-4.76.285-4.273 3.758-3.917 5.459-3.205.19-4.842-4.431-6.29-6.765-6.41-2.294-.355-7.619-.141-10.563 3.562-2.943 3.703-7.082 7.477-8.783 8.901-4.462 4.368-8.506 2.69-10.326 1.306-.989-1.108-3.323-4.13-1.899-7.359 1.425-3.228 4.946-1.74 6.528-.593-.854-5.602-6.369-6.45-9.02-6.172-1.068.079-3.679.593-5.578 2.018-1.899 1.424-5.302 6.448-6.766 8.782-.633 1.306-2.919 4.297-7.002 5.816-4.083 1.52-7.161-1.028-8.19-2.492-.633-1.108-1.519-3.917 0-6.29 1.52-2.375 4.352-1.306 5.579-.476-1.519-3.418-3.482-5.222-4.273-5.696-2.057-1.662-7.762-3.039-14.124 4.747-6.361 7.786-12.858 8.783-15.31 8.308v12.344h94.304v-12.33ZM376.016 14.776c-1.808-.694-3.447-2.111-3.271-4.76.285-4.273 3.759-3.917 5.46-3.205.19-4.842-4.431-6.29-6.765-6.41-2.295-.355-7.62-.141-10.563 3.562-2.944 3.703-7.082 7.477-8.783 8.901-4.463 4.368-8.506 2.69-10.326 1.306-.989-1.108-3.323-4.13-1.899-7.359 1.424-3.228 4.945-1.74 6.528-.593-.855-5.602-6.37-6.45-9.021-6.172-1.068.079-3.679.593-5.578 2.018-1.899 1.424-5.301 6.448-6.765 8.782-.633 1.306-2.92 4.297-7.003 5.816-4.083 1.52-7.16-1.028-8.189-2.492-.633-1.108-1.519-3.917 0-6.29 1.519-2.375 4.352-1.306 5.578-.476-1.519-3.418-3.481-5.222-4.273-5.696-2.057-1.662-7.762-3.039-14.123 4.747-6.362 7.786-12.858 8.783-15.311 8.308v12.344h94.304v-12.33Z"/>
            </g>
          </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your codepen shows errors on the console - fix that and you should be right - hint: waveColorTL is undefined in the handler

Comment: `tanWaveTL` is also `undefined` ... `gsap.timeline` isn't a function (you've imported such that you'd need to use `gsap.gsap.timeline` - as the answer to your previous question states - console.log is your best debugging friend, but you have to see what's logged to the console to make it useful

Comment: @Bravo Thank you for your comment! I am very new to this and I am taking a course in JS and I am confused about how said items are undefined. I have updated my CodePen and did some console.log and I can see that waveColorTL is undefined but I guess I am simply unsure how to define it. From looking at my instructor's code for a previous demo, I haven't done anything less.

Comment: I told you how to find out why - *console.log is your best debugging friend* - have you looked?